# How do you have $\text{Var}(X) = 0 \iff P(X = a) = 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ to be a random variable and $\mathbb{E[X]}$ to be the expected value of $X$. Now when the variance is $0$, we have $\mathbb{E}[(X - E[X])^2]=0 \implies X - E[X] = 0$. This shows that $X$ is a constant. Assume it to be a non-zero constant, that is to say, $X\neq 0$.

From here once can conclude that : $$X = \mathbb{E}[X] = \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)P(\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X] \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} P(\omega) \implies 1 = \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} P(\omega)$$

Now [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) shows that $\text{Var}(X) = 0 \iff P(X=a)=1$. I don't quite get their reference here: $\color{red}{(1)}$ Do they mean that $\exists \ a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $P(X=a)=1$ or that $P(X=a)=1 \ \forall \ a\in \mathbb{R}\color{red}{?}$

Still, consider the space $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the random variable $X = 0.5$ such that the respective probabilities are $0.5,0.5,0,0,0$. It turns out that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \displaystyle\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)P(\omega) = (0.5)^2 + (0.5)^2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0.5 = X$. $\color{red}{(2)}$ Here, $P(X = 0.5)$ happens with probability$\color{red}{?}$ I think there's something wrong with this.

---

*To put emphasis on the questions I've got doubts in, I have numbered them (in color).*

Edit: The Wiki page has now been re-edited. The first question doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning 1):

What they mean is: $$\exists a\in\mathbb R\;P(X=a)=1$$

Observe that the statement $\forall a\in\mathbb R\;P(X=a)=1$ cannot be true. It would lead for instance to: $$P(X\in\{0,1\})=P(X=0)+P(X=1)=1+1=2$$ which is absurd.

Concerning 2):

If $X$ is a random variable defined on $\Omega$ then $X=0.5$ is actually an abbreviation of the statement that $X(\omega)=0.5$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

So:

$$\{X=0.5\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=0.5\}=\Omega$$ and consequently: $$P(X=0.5)=P(\Omega)=1$$

Comment: Ah! This addresses all of my doubts. Thank you so much drhab.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$var (X) =0$ iff **there exists** $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $P(X=a)=1$. It is impossible to have two different real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $P(X=a)=1$ and $P(X=b)=1$ because $P(X \in \{a,b\})$ would  then be $1+1=2$!

Comment: Oh darn. I missed the **there exists** term in the statement. It's obvious then, thank you.